# Cannot perform aggregation on sub query in EF core 3.0

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-3.0

I am getting the error after migrating to EF Core 3.0

> Cannot perform aggregation on sub query...

Here is my query:

```
var query= (from TestAttempt in Wallet.LD_AssociateTestAttempt
            join contentTest in Wallet.LD_Test on new { TestId = TestAttempt.TestId, Type = TestType.Content.Value, IsDeleted = false, IsEnable = true }
                 equals new { TestId = contentTest.TestId, Type = contentTest.Type, Isdeleted = contentTest.IsDeleted, IsEnable = contentTest.Enable }

            let NoOfQuestions = contentTest.LD_TestDetails.Where(a => !a.IsDeleted).Select(a => a.NoOfQuestions).Sum()
            let TotalMarks = NoOfQuestions * contentTest.QuestionPerMarks
            where TestAttempt.IsActive && !TestAttempt.IsDeleted
            group new { TotalMarks, TestAttempt.Marks, TestAttempt.TestStartDate, TestAttempt.TestEndDate, TestAttempt.TestCompletionDate } by new { TestAttempt.AssociateTestId } into G
            select new
                   {
                       AssociateTestId = G.Key.AssociateTestId,
                       Marks = G.Sum(a => a.Marks),
                       TotalMarks = G.Sum(a => a.TotalMarks),
                       TestCompletionDate = G.Max(a => a.TestCompletionDate),
                       TestEndDate = G.Max(a => a.TestEndDate),
                   });
```

The exact line where I am facing the issue is

```
let NoOfQuestions = contentTest.LD_TestDetails.Where(a => !a.IsDeleted).Select(a => a.NoOfQuestions).Sum()
```

Could somebody help me on this? I am new to EF Core

Answer (score 0):

> Old behavior
>
> Before 3.0, when EF Core couldn't convert an expression that was part
> of a query to either SQL or a parameter, it automatically evaluated
> the expression on the client. By default, client evaluation of
> potentially expensive expressions only triggered a warning.
>
> New behavior
>
> Starting with 3.0, EF Core only allows expressions in the top-level
> projection (the last Select() call in the query) to be evaluated on
> the client. When expressions in any other part of the query can't be
> converted to either SQL or a parameter, an exception is thrown.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client

it's mean your query is Complex for convert to SQL query and you must be simplify your EF-query or break to two or three query.

Comment: So, Any solution/alternative for this?

Comment: break your query to some sub-query